# Trying to stringify an array of objects from a combined array

Tags: arrays, json, object, stringify

I'm working with facebook, and I'm trying to combine some of the information from a group posts with the name and user id of the user that posted to the group.  Here is my code:

```
    var theGroup = component.get('v.feedAPI');
    var theToken;
    var lastTime = component.get('v.feedScraped');;
    lastTime = lastTime.replace(" ", "T");

    var nameAndMessage = {};
    nameAndMessage['posts'] = [];

    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            theToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            FB.api('/' + theGroup + '/feed?access_token=' + theToken, 'GET', {
                    "fields": "message,updated_time,id,type",
                    "since": lastTime.toString()
            },
                function(response1) {
                    var i = 0;
                    var len = response1.data.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var ii = 0;
                        FB.api('/' + response1.data[i].id, 'GET', {
                                "fields": "from,id,message"
                            },
                            function (response) {

                                var theKey = 'post' + ii;
                                nameAndMessage["posts"][Number(ii)] = {};
                                nameAndMessage["posts"][Number(ii)]["uName"] = response.from.name;
                                nameAndMessage["posts"][Number(ii)]["uId"] = response.from.id;
                                nameAndMessage["posts"][Number(ii)]["thePost"] = response1.data[ii].message;
                                nameAndMessage["posts"][Number(ii)]["createdT"] = response1.data[ii].updated_time;
                                nameAndMessage["posts"][Number(ii)]["postID"] = response1.data[ii].id;
                                ii++;
                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            );
            console.log(nameAndMessage);
            var convertString = JSON.stringify(nameAndMessage);
            console.log(convertString);


        } else {
            alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {
        scope: 'user_managed_groups',
        return_scopes: true
    });
```

The string produced by my stringify is:

> {"posts":[]}

The actual results of "nameAndMessage" produce 25 records but appears like this:

> {posts: Array(0)}
>   posts
>   :
>   Array(25)

[screen shot of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3k3J.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like `response1.data.length` might be "0", n'est ce pas?

Comment: @paulsm4 So, response and response1 both return 25 records, and stringify just fine.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the output of the array.

Comment: I do not know JavaScript but it seems to me that you are using 'posts' as a key in line 7 nameAndMessage['posts'] = []; but other places you are using nameAndMessage["posts"] ,and I believe they are becoming two different key value pairs and the data is getting added to nameAndMessage["posts"];

Comment: @dsTYRO yeah, the reason I did that, was because before doing so, my stringify would only return [].  Again, it would have all of the 25 records in it, but would not stringify.